# how to create private Ethereum network after post merge?

Tags: private-blockchain

i want to create private Ethereum, i don't want to sync blocks of TestNet or mainnet. Please help in this regard. thank

Answer (score 0):

Just search something like "run private net ethereum".
You can use [ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-ui) that is very simple, or like geth from cli